# Why does my app look simulated on the ipad?

Tags: swift, xcode

my app is not scaling the ipad screen and it has this zoom in and zoom out button on the bottom right. Is there somewhere in the settings I can turn this off?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the General Tab for your project and select the appropriate setting in Deployment Info.

In Xcode 11 you need to make sure the iPad checkbox is checked.

[image]

In Xcode 10 you need to make sure Universal is selected in the drop down menu for Devices.

[image]